# Receive infrared number from circuit playground express on arduino

Tags: express, arduino, circuit

On the circuit playground express theres a network function, where you can send a number through ir. Now I would like my arduino to read this number, and respond when it reads the number.
I've already connected a IR Receiver Diode to my arduino and used the following code with library:

```
#include <IRremote.h>
int RECV_PIN = 11;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop()
{
  if (irrecv.decode(&results))
    {
     Serial.println(results.value);
     irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
    }
}
```

The serial monitor, doesn't show the circuit playground number when I send it.
Does somebody now how to read the number send by the circuit playground express?

Comment: What do you get instead? `results.value` is a long, which print can show. Perhaps you want to see it in HEX ?

Comment: It doesn't show any values on the arduino when I send the number from the circuit playground

Comment: Wrong forum here, if you have the wiring wrong. Sorry

Comment: no the wiring is correct, the problem is te code, it receives ir signals from, say a remote controller, but not from the circuit playground and I want it to receive that

Comment: Then the problem is your sender? Which "circuit playground" are you talking about BTW?

Comment: the adafruit circuit playground express, I used the send ir number function from network in make code

Comment: What is the value of `results->decode_type`? Also see (or run) https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/blob/master/examples/IRrecvDump/IRrecvDump.ino